# How to place an element at the bottom of a page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place the `#second_row` div at the bottom of the page. I've tried different solutions but none of them works.

```css
#second_row {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="background-color: transparent">TH1</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="background-color: transparent">TH1</th>
            <th style="background-color: transparent">TH2</th>
            <th style="background-color: transparent">TH3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="second_row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed position to appear in bottom you have to mention the position also like **top, right, left, bottom.** and there is no need of **margins** with fixed positioned element

So your code will work like this::

```
 #second_row {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou, that worked for me! What do I have to do if I want to put the row a few pixels upper? No fixex position + margin?

Comment: You can add bottom: 10px as per you need. If you find my answer helpful please give a thumbs up.